# Creating a method to add a new record to a table in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am a newbie in Rails. I have three tables players, rosters and lineups. I have the model entries to create the relationships where players belong_to rosters and lineups, rosters has_many players, and lineups has_many players.

The problem I have is when I created the roster I have a roster_name attribute and I am able to add a single player to it. I want to add more players to the same roster but I am struggling with how to add a new player to the roster. The default new view calls the _form partial which expects me to create an entirely new roster and that will allow me to add a single user again.

What is the rails way to add a new player to an existing roster. Please help me understand what components I need. Do I need a new partial that I can call to have a field to add the new player? Do I have to create a new method or controller? What I am assuming is it that I need a way to reference the existing roster while being able to add the new player_id. Any help would be great.

Here is my models/controllers and view

```
My model roster.rb
class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :players

    accepts_nested_attributes_for  :players, :allow_destroy => true
end
My model player.rb
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :roster
end
My controller rosters_controller.rb
def new
    @roster = Roster.new
    @players = Player.all
End

My roster view
<%= form_for(@roster) do |f| %>                                   
  <% if @roster.errors.any? %>                                    
    <div id="error_explanation">                                  
      <h2><%= pluralize(@roster.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this roster from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @roster.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>                           
      <% end %>                                       
      </ul>                                           
    </div>                                            
  <% end %>                                           

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :player_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :player_id %>
  <%= collection_select("roster", "player_id", @players, "id", "gname") %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :player_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :player_id %>
  <%= collection_select("roster", "player_id", @players, "id", "gname") %>

  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its a many-to-many association, `has_many :through` association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model. Now association declarations could look like this:

```
class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roster_players
  has_many :players, :through => :roster_players
end

class RosterPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :roster
  belongs_to :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roster_players
  has_many :roster, :through => :roster_players
end
```

**Step 1:**
Generate association model.

```
$> rails g model roster_player roster:references player:references
$> rake db:migrate
```

**Step 2:**
What you require is the way to accept nested attributes. Go through this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and read about [nested_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). The code form that rails cast has been extracted out as a gem by Ryan Bates and is very useful.

Update your gemfile to require this gem

```
gem 'nested_form'
$> bundle install
```

Next run the generator to create the JavaScript file. This will automatically detect if you are using jQuery or Prototype.

```
rails g nested_form:install
```

Running the generator will add a file `nested_form.js` which should be included after the jQuery or Prototype framework.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "nested_form" %>
```

Let us extract nested attributes into a partial named `_roster_player_fields.html.erb`

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :player_id, "Player" %>
  <%= f.select :player_id, Player.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true } %>
</div>
```

What we want to do here is add fields for each of the roster palyers to the form. We can use the fields_for method to manage associated fields in a form, passing it the name of the associated model and then loop through all of the associated player records and create a form builder for each of them. The builder will render the partial for each player.

```
<%= form_for(@roster) do |f| %>                                   
  <% if @roster.errors.any? %>                                    
    <div id="error_explanation">                                  
      <h2><%= pluralize(@roster.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this roster from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @roster.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>                           
      <% end %>                                       
      </ul>                                           
    </div>                                            
  <% end %>                                           

  <% f.fields_for :roster_players do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'roster_player_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "[+] Add Player", f, :roster_players %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When this form is rendered it will look like it did before. This is because a new roster won’t have any players associated with it and therefore none of the player fields will be shown. Ultimately we want to have an “Add Player” link on the form but we can just create a roster_player in the RosterController’s new action and its fields are displayed.

```
def new
  @roster = Roster.new
  @roster.roster_players.build
End
```

By default nested attribute updating is turned off, you can enable it using the `#accepts_nested_attributes_for` class method. When you enable nested attributes an attribute writer is defined on the model. This should work and hope it helps.

Comment: I seem to be conflicted with the nested attribute paradigm. In the example it uses a comments model as a nested attribute to an article model. The comments only exist in relation to the article. I want to associate a player_id with a roster and have the player exist even without the roster. So in the application use, the players will be added first then rosters will be created which selects the players that are in the roster. Some players will not be on the roster and I plan to have more that one roster. Does the example you sent me to still fit? I am having problems accessing player.

Comment: Update the question with code on how your models are structured.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I didn't see your reply. I was expecting a seperate field. Here is my code. I am trying to add many players by id to the roster table. I know my view is flawed right now. I would like to have many fields for the player id's available in the new roster field, select the players from the collection select drop down and add each populated field.